# jenkins pipeline - parameter from function - Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to pass return value of a function as parameter.

```
@NonCPS
def getLastRelease() {
    def RES = sh(script: '''cat version''', returnStdout: true).trim()
    return RES
}
pipeline{
    parameters {
            choice(name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', choices: '${getLastRelease()}', description: 'desc')
        }
}
```

But for some reason it does not work - if i try:

```
'${getLastRelease()}'
```

I am getting error:

> durable-73075a87/script.sh: line 1: ${getLastRelease()}: bad
>   substitution

if i use:

```
"${getLastRelease()}"
```

I am getting error:

> [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline [Pipeline] sh [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException:
>   Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing Perhaps you forgot
>   to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node,
>   dockerNode

Comment: I am not completely sure if you can or want to provide dynamic choices for user input parameters. Default values sure, but choices not so much.

Comment: I want to get the release version, which is actually generated by bash script, and i want it to be default option. The script is correct and I am able to echo this value inside the pipeline `RES = getLastRelease()` `echo "${RES}"`
But for some reason it does not work for parameter

Comment: If you want it to be the default value, then you need to use the `defaultValue` key.

Comment: tried, this, I am getting very same error `hudson.FilePath is missing `

Comment: Ok then you probably need to use the full parameter class to do this.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by "full parameter class" as I am quite new to pipeline. I tried calling the function directly without the parameter altogether and it works perfectly `projectBuildStep.checkoutProject("${getLastRelease()}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

1. Remove the annotation `@NonCPS`, since NonCPS functions [should not use Pipeline steps internally](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design).
2. Since you execute shell scripts, wrap the expressions in your function in a `node {...}` block.
3. Simply invoke the function `getLastRelease()` inside the choice the parameter without the quotes or the curly braces.

Working sample:

```
def getLastRelease() {
    node {
        def RES = sh (script: 'cat version', returnStdout: true).trim()
        return RES
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', choices: [getLastRelease(), <more choices, ...>], description: 'desc')
    }
}
```

Comment: node{} and caling function without any braces did the trick. Thanks!